# Uninitialized string offset: 0 codeigniter index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: index.php

Line Number: 154
```

here is the code

```
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") //line number 154
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
     // echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
    curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl_exec` doesn't return an array, just raw data in a string ... if you need the first character of the string you can use

```
$sResult{0}
```

Comment: you need to change the next line as well `$sResult[0] = " "` to `$sResult = " " . substr( $sResult, 1 );`

Comment: first of all, remove the evil '@' and then check `if ( $sResult !== FALSE )`

Answer (score 0):

$sResult is not having offset zero. try to do

```
print_r($sResult);
```

before line 154 , and you will find out the error reason  and solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely returning `false` from a failed request. You should make that one of your test cases before testing for actual results.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a chance that $sResult is returning false, which is a boolean and not a string or an array.
Try changing the conditional to:

if ($sResult !== FALSE && $sResult[0]=="O") 
{$sResult[0]=" ";}